# Formula field - Hyperlink to record page (SF and Community)

Tags: community, formula-field

I have a formula field that displays a text and has a link to record page, like this:

```
HYPERLINK('/'+ Id , Name__c)
```

The problem is, this has to work inside Salesforce but also in the community, and the problem is that in the community we have a relative url, like this:

```
www.community.com/something
```

So the final url using the formula field will be:

```
www.community.com/123456789
```

And it needs to be:

```
www.community.com/something/s/detail/123456789
```

But if i had the '/s/detail' to the formula field it will stop working on Salesforce side.

Anyone has a solution for this? Using different fields it's not an option because they access the records in the community using the same listviews.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using CASE function? you should try somthing like this below.

```
HyperLink( CASE(LEFT(BASE URL),"your communityurl", 
   "www.community.com/something/s/detail/123456789" 
   LEFT(BASE URL),"https://instance.salesforce.com/", "'/'+ Id , Name__c"))
```

You can get your base url like below

```
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))
```

let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hello, i was trying to avoid using a condition based on the community url because if we change this URL i have to update the formula field.

Comment: But thanks, of course this is a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

community record page URL for an object record page
SUBSTITUTE($Api.Partner_Server_URL_90, RIGHT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_90 ,LEN('my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/9.0/XXXXXXXXXXX4xGa')), '') + 'my.site.com/'+ Site prefix(store in custom metadata and use here ) + 'detail/'+your record id

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same thought today and figured I might be stuck here, but realized I could solve for this a slightly different way that ultimately worked for my use case.

Create a text-based formula that looks at the user type because we have standard users leveraging Service Cloud and other users in a Customer Community. You can see the users that use SC would get the first URL and the Customer Community would get the other!

```
IF(TEXT($Profile.UserType) = 'Standard',

LEFT($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_590, FIND( '/services', $Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_590))

+ Id,

LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_590, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_590))

+ 's/detail/' + Id

)
```

Hope this helps!